# System.TypeLoadException with Mono and ASP.NET in Arduino project

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache, mono, arduino

I am trying to use a web page to control an LCD screen on an Arduino. The web page works when run from Visual Studio (2012), but when trying to deploy to my Apache server with mod_mono, I get this cryptic error. This is the complete error:

```
Could not load type 'System.Web.UI.ScriptResourceDefinition' from assembly
'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): mscorlib.
Exception stack trace:
    at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
    at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

And the Mono version on the bottom of the page reports as:

```
Version Information: 3.3.0 (master/6cd4ddc); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020
```

All I'm doing in the application is taking text from a box and sending it over serial to my Arduino.

The error I'm getting doesn't really tell me anything, as far as I know anyway. Could it be because serial ports wouldn't work when run from an actual server? It works fine with Visual Studios server, and the XPS test that comes with Mono works fine with my Apache server.

I wanted to make this web page so my friend from across the country could send messages to my Arduino's LCD. :) Many thanks to anyone who can help me.

EDIT: After moving System.Web.Extensions.dll from Mono's folder to the bin folder, I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
Assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not contain a Web resource with name 'jquery'.

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.Web.Extensions.
Exception stack trace:
  at System.Web.UI.ScriptReferenceBase.VerifyAssemblyContainsResource (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String resourceName, System.Web.UI.WebResourceAttribute& wra) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.ScriptReferenceBase.GetScriptName (System.String releaseName, Boolean isDebugMode, System.String[] supportedUICultures, System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.Web.UI.WebResourceAttribute& wra) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetUrl (System.Web.UI.ScriptManager scriptManager, Boolean zip) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterScriptReference (System.Web.UI.Control control, System.Web.UI.ScriptReferenceBase script, Boolean loadScriptsBeforeUI) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnPreRenderComplete (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreRenderComplete (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessLoadComplete () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.InternalProcessRequest () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Sometimes I get this error, sometimes the same one as before. Depends on Apache's mood I guess.

Answer (score 0):

That class is in [System.Web.Extensions.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptresourcedefinition%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), please make sure that DLL is in your bin folder.

Comment: After putting that file in, I get a new complaint from that file: 
Assembly 'System.Web.Extensions' does not contain a Web resource with name 'jquery'. I tried both the Microsoft dll and Mono, neither work unfortunately.

Comment: Also, when the Arduino wasn't unplugged, I got an error saying COM3 wasn't available, so it's not that.

Comment: edit your question and paste both errors that you mention, we cannot read your computer's screen from here

Comment: ok, use Mono's dll, not MS.NET, and run your app with the "--debug" flag passed to mono executable (so we get line numbers on the stack trace, and we can determine what line of code is looking for that jquery script)

Comment: Is there any way to host an ASP.NET site on my own computer without using Mono? I have Windows 7 and OS X Lion. If not, then I'll just try a different language; it's not worth all this trouble with Mono. I'm just doing this as an experiment for fun, so don't want to spend so much time on it.

Comment: if you don't want to spend time on improving something so the NEXT person can benefit from your experience, then you don't deserve to use the Mono project which contains millions of altruist contributions from people all over the world which didn't mind to do it in the past, in contrast with you

Comment: Guess I won't use Mono then. I asked this question for myself, not for other people. That's not being selfish, just trying to get something to work.