# How to run a .net webservice using Monodevelop?

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I am new to Monodevelop. I have downloaded Monodevelop 3.0.6. and the framework for mono. I have written a C# webservice using the MONOdevelop and on running, it gives error as

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): mscorlib.

Is there any need of new software to be installed or else apache to be started or something.

Comment: release or debug mode? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401425/system-typeloadexception-with-mono-and-asp-net-in-arduino-project

Comment: Debug mode. Please explain in detail.                                   The .asmx file is                                                                        ......................................................................<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="Testing.Testing" %>
 
using System;
using System.Web.Services;


namespace Testing
{
    internal class Testing
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
        }
    }
}

Comment: you gave the version of monodevelop but not the version of mono

Comment: Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.5